# Why does Lazy<T> using ExecutionAndPublication behave differently with yielded IEnumerables?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, lazy-initialization

I had a problem in my code where a Lazy initializer was called more frequently than what I expected. From the documentation, I expected that using LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication would ensure my initializer function was only ever called once, for example if accessing numbers.Value after defining:

```
numbers = new Lazy<IEnumerable<int>>(
        () => GetNumbers(),
        LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication
    );
```

However, what I have found is that if the initialization function yields its results, the initialization function gets called more than once. I presume this has to with yields delayed execution but I only have a fuzzy sense why.

**Question:**

In the code below, why do the respective initialization functions get executed a different number of times?

```
void Main()
{
    var foo         = new foo();
    var tasks       = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {foreach (var number in foo.Numbers) Debug.WriteLine(number);})); 
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    tasks.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {foreach (var letter in foo.Letters) Debug.WriteLine(letter);})); 
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

public class foo
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers => numbers.Value;
    public IEnumerable<char> Letters => letters.Value;
    readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<int>> numbers;
    readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<char>> letters;

    public foo()
    {
        numbers = new Lazy<IEnumerable<int>>(
            () => GetNumbers(),
            LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication
        );
        letters = new Lazy<IEnumerable<char>>(
            () => GetLetters().ToList(), //ToList enumerates all yielded letters, creating the expected call once behavior
            LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication
        );
    }

    protected IEnumerable<char> GetLetters()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(GetLetters)} Called");
        yield return 'a';
        yield return 'b';
        yield return 'c';
        yield break;
    }
    protected IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(GetNumbers)} Called");
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read up on how `yield` works.  Basically your method is turn into a state machine.  And each time you iterate it your code will be called.  This actually has nothing to do with `Lazy<T>` and as @dcg points out using `yield` is already lazy, so no need for wrapping it in a `Lazy<T>` object.  If you want to cache the results of your method in memory you can use `ToList` and then `Lazy<T>` could be used to defer when the method is iterated by the `ToList` call and the results are put into memory.

Answer (score 5):

> I had a problem in my code where a Lazy initializer was called more frequently than what I expected.

No, the initializer of the lazy is called once. The initializer of the lazy is

```
() => GetNumbers()
```

and that is called exactly once.

`GetNumbers` returns an `IEnumerable<int>` -- a sequence of integers.

When you `foreach` that sequence, it calls `GetEnumerator` to get an enumerator, and then calls `MoveNext` on the enumerator object until `MoveNext` returns `false`.

You've said that you want the sequence to be enumerated as:

```
the first time MoveNext is called, do a writeline and produce 1
the second time MoveNext is called, produce 2
the third time MoveNext is called, produce 3
the fourth time MoveNext is called, produce 4
Every subsequent time MoveNext is called, return false
```

So *every time you enumerate the sequence*, that's what happens.

Can you explain what you expected to happen? I am interested to learn why people have false beliefs about computer programs.

Also it is not clear to me why you are using `Lazy` at all. You would typically use `Lazy` to avoid expensive work until it is needed, but sequences *already* defer work until they are enumerated.

Comment: The OP indicated surprise that the two snippets provided behaved differently, so I think it's pretty fair to say that they expected the first sequence to behave the way the second one does.

Comment: @Servy: Plainly. I was hoping to get a bit more detail around the "mental model" of what justified that belief.

Comment: @EricLippert: I will note that when I first encountered `Lazy`, my mental model was "Use this if you want something to be initialized once. 
 Initialization will be deferred." Thus, I would use a `Lazy` if A) I needed a static something to be initialized once, B) I did not mind if initialization was deferred, and C) I was worried about race conditions.  C isn't really part of the mental model; it's there to scramble my mental toolbox so that better solutions aren't sitting at the top.  Now `Lazy` is tagged in my mental model with, "Use caution.  Previous mental model lead to bad decisions."